# How to make Linux to re-detect network interfaces?

Tags: linux, networking

For some reason, `ifcfg-eth*` under `/etc/sysconfig/network-script` were deleted.

Are there any tools that could detect network interfaces and re-generate these files?

---

Another question :

If I manually added `ifcfg-eth0`, is there any method to make it work without reboot?

I tried `/etc/init.d/networking restart`, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Red hat, CentOS, or what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also, since it looks like you're running some sort of Redhat-derivative, you can try

```
 system-config-network
```

Configure the interfaces, then run

```
 service network restart
```

Comment: It seems  system-config-network generates files under /etc/sysconfig/network/devices. Need to copy it to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts. Then that's the "System eth0"

Answer (score 1):

cat /proc/net/dev and regenerate those yourself.
ifdown ethX && ifup ethX should work for restarting that interface

Answer (score 0):

One Red Hat and derivatives, I found the best thing to do is consolidate the contents and then delete all but one of the ifcfg-eth* files, and then soft link them all together. That way, what the system is running cannot get out of sync with what you thought you set up, but did not actually take, in the configuration menus.

While this move may seem radical, it has worked well with many hundreds of server years of combined up time.